# SignalR startup exposes timing gap in document "ready" handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

In [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26454331/1637105), I described by problems wiring up a SignalR app that allows a POST controller action to call back to the specific client that triggered the POST.  The solution I implemented involves fetching the SignalR connection ID in JavaScript once the SignalR stuff is wired up and storing that connection ID in a hidden form field.  That hidden form field is then sent to the POST action when the user clicks the submit button on the form.

The obvious problem with this scheme is that it takes a couple of seconds for SignalR to set up the connection; if the user clicks the submit button during this time then the POST action gets a null string for the connection ID.  Ok, simple solution (I would have thought): Disable the submit button on form load, and re-enable it once the connection is established.  (Note that the HTML has to start with the button enabled in case JavaScript is disabled in the user's browser; I must use JS to disable the button only if JS is enabled.)

But herein lies my problem: It seems that, at least in IE 11: **Referencing the autogenerated SignalR hub script causes about a two second delay between when the browser displays the page (and allows the user to click on buttons) and when the page ready script runs.** During that two second window, the user can click the submit button and send a null connection ID to the POST action.

My view looks like this.  Note that this line:

```
    <!-- Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

causes the page to display for a couple of seconds before the page "ready" script executes!

```
@model SignalRTest.Models.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SignalRConnectionId)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go to it!</button>
}

<div id="hidden-msg" hidden="hidden">
    <p>Please wait...</p>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <!-- Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <!-- SignalR script to update the page -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Disable the submit buttons (until we have a connection ID)
            $('input[type="submit"], button[type="submit"]')
                .prop('disabled', true)
                .attr('data-sbs-enable-me', '');

            // Get a reference to the server "hub" class (camelCase)
            var hub = $.connection.myHub;

            // Create a function that the hub can call
            hub.client.myCallback = function () {
                $('#hidden-msg').show();
            };

            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start()
                .done(function () {
                    // Get our connection ID and store it in a hidden field so that it is
                    // sent to the POST action
                    $('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.SignalRConnectionId)')
                        .attr('value', $.connection.hub.id);

                    // Enable the buttons
                    $('[data-sbs-enable-me]')
                        .prop('disabled', false)
                        .removeAttr('data-sbs-enable-me');
                })

                .fail(function () { });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try connecting without using the hub proxy script that is generated by your SignalR hub.

```
@section scripts {
<!-- Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- SignalR script to update the page -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Disable the submit buttons (until we have a connection ID)
        $('input[type="submit"], button[type="submit"]')
            .prop('disabled', true)
            .attr('data-sbs-enable-me', '');

        // Get a reference to the server "hub" class (camelCase)
        var connection = $.hubConnection();
        var myHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('myHub');

        // Create a function that the hub can call
        myHubProxy.on('myCallback', function() {
            $("#hidden-msg').show();
        });

        // Start the connection.
        connection.start()
            .done(function () {
                // Get our connection ID and store it in a hidden field so that it is
                // sent to the POST action
                $('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.SignalRConnectionId)')
                    .attr('value', connection.id);

                // Enable the buttons
                $('[data-sbs-enable-me]')
                    .prop('disabled', false)
                    .removeAttr('data-sbs-enable-me');
            })

            .fail(function () { });
    });
</script>
}
```

The documentation for SignalR client configurations can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client). It outlines how to set things up using the generated proxy and without the generated proxy. Only time I have used the gerated proxy was when working on a POC. But usually I set my hubs up to not broadcast the generated script so it is not visible to the outside world.

Comment: Thanks GJohn.  I had to edit your answer a bit to get it to work.  I replaced a couple of references to "$.connection.hub" with "connection", and added a missing parenthesis after the .on function.  I also added some comments.  My edits are awaiting "peer review".

Comment: Ah yes, sorry the start method is a little different once you get away from using the generated proxy.